# BigQueryOperator : No matching signature for operator = for argument types: DATE, INT64

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

When I run this query on BigQuery UI:

```
DELETE FROM `A.Books.items` where Date='2018-08-31'
```

The query works great.
However when I'm trying to do it on Airflow:

```
delete_sql = '''DELETE FROM `A.Books.items` where Date = {0}'''.format('2018-08-31') # // later this will be variable
delete_old= BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bigquery_delete',
    bql=delete_sql,
    destination_dataset_table=False,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    delegate_to=False,
    use_legacy_sql = 'False',
    udf_config=False,
    dag=dag,
)
```

it returns:

```
Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {u'reason': u'invalidQuery', u'message': u'No matching signature for operator = for argument types: DATE, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [1:52]', u'location': u'query'
```

`Date` is a column with type `DATE` in `items` table.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you able to run this query from the Bigquery UI?

Comment: @kaxil Yes. and I found the solution: changed to `Date = cast('{0}' as DATE)`  I really wish this was explained better in the docs of airflow. My native query runs as is on BigQuery... I don't understand why airflow requires different syntax

Comment: Airflow doesn't require a different syntax, it would pass your query as is to BigQuery Api.

Comment: Are you using StandardSQL or Legacy SQL in BigQuery UI?

Comment: @kaxil standard. note the: use_legacy_sql = 'False',

Comment: @kaxil I suspect that airflow has issue with the word Date... maybe he confuses parsing the query thinking that is a type rather than a column name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179273/discussion-between-kaxil-and-programmer120).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
delete_sql = '''DELETE FROM A.Books.items where Date = '{0}' '''.format('2018-08-31')
```

You need quotes when you want to replace the strings.